# symfony2 (pre)validate form before post (on load)

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

## I need to validate user profile form when loading page (without post) and display errors.

It turned out to be quite a challenge.

### Requirements

- errors must be displayed in same manner as after post would be.
- required fields must have `field is empty` error message.

**Universal and almost working solution**: error messages are displayed, that's fine. However they are not highlighted ***because*** form element does not receive `has-error` style class ***because*** form field is marked as valid ***because*** `valid` is checking for `submitted` and submitted is false because is was not submitted.

```
 $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($form);
    if (count($errors)) {
        /** @var ConstraintViolation $error */
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            // data.firstname
            if (preg_match('/^data\.(.*)/', $error->getPropertyPath(), $matches)) {
                $path = $matches[1];
            } // children[schoolGrades].data
            elseif (preg_match('/^children\[(.*?)\]\.data/', $error->getPropertyPath(), $matches)) {
                $path = $matches[1];
            } else {
                throw new \Exception(sprintf('Cannot parse field path from "%s"', $error->getPropertyPath()));
            }
            $formElement = $form->get($path);
            $formElement->addError(new FormError($error->getMessage()));
        }
    }
    $form->handleRequest($request);
```

### Question

Is there a way set `valid` to false or `submitted` to true? Maybe there is entirely different solution? I find it hard to believe that I am the first to implement this as I found it hard to believe that I cannot retrieve data as array from form I built and set data with `$form->setData($user);`.

### Other information

**Found solutions that does not work for me**:

1. `$form->submit([], false);` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997307/846432). Not good - if required field is empty error will not be displayed.
2. Using `ViolationMapper();` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21705112/846432). Simply does not work for me... :/

**Implemented working solution with drawbacks**: create user data as array with data set from user entity. Problem: have to maintain function when changing form and/or User entity.

```
public static function handleRequest(User $user, FormInterface $form, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->get(UserWizardModel::URL_GET_PARAM_LAST_STEP) && !$request->get($form->getName())) {
        $schoolGradeIdArray = [];
        foreach ($user->getSchoolGrades() as $schoolGrade) {
            $schoolGradeIdArray[] = $schoolGrade->getId();
        }
        $userAsArray = [
            'firstname' => $user->getFirstname(),
            'lastname' => $user->getLastname(),
            'profileType' => '',
            'phone' => $user->getPhone(),
            'schoolGrades' => $schoolGradeIdArray,
            'profileSchool' => $user->getProfileSchool()->getId(),
        ];
        $form->submit($userAsArray);
    } else {
        $form->handleRequest($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to do the same - I ended up using your implemented solution.
Although I checked this with a form factory and put the error there:
($form->get('field')->addError(new FormError('error message'));)
The other way would be to just parse the form and validate the given data on the front-end with Javascript.

Comment: you could also put that stuff in a session object (or a request Response) and check in the twig template for any of these errors.

Comment: Yes, yours are valid suggestions but for me the goal is to have universal solution so I don't have change code in multiple places if I changes constraints, entity fields or template.